# How to use a reset button Java arkanoid game

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, reset

So  this is part of my game panel for my game. I got my start button to work, and created a reset button but I don't know how to reset the game every single time it is pressed. Does anyone know how to reset the game to its original position after you press "Reset"? Right now it will display the words "You have died", but it doesn't do anything when I press Reset.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
   private Brick[][] bary;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.black;
   private BufferedImage myImage;
   private Graphics myBuffer;
   private Ball ball = new Ball();
   public Bumper bumper;
   private Timer t;
   private int hits = 0;  
   private boolean isPlayingGame = false;

   public GamePanel()
   {
      myImage =  new BufferedImage(600, 800, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      myBuffer = myImage.getGraphics();
      myBuffer.setColor(BACKGROUND);
      myBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, 600,800);

      JButton sbutton = new JButton("Start");
      sbutton.setFocusable(false);
      sbutton.addActionListener(new Listener());
      add(sbutton);
      JButton rbutton = new JButton("Reset");
      rbutton.setFocusable(false);
      rbutton.addActionListener(new Listener());
      add(rbutton);

      bary = new Brick[5][14];

      bumper = new Bumper(270, 775, 60, 10, Color.BLUE);
      ball = new Ball(300, 400, 10, Color.RED);

      t = new Timer(5, new Listener());

      setFocusable(true);
      //addKeyListener(new Key());
   }

   // tick method is called every 10ms by Arkanoid.java
   // only does stuff if game is actually being played
   public void tick()
   {
      if(isPlayingGame)
      {
         ball.move(600,800, 600, 800); 
         death(ball);
      }
   }


   // these get called by the BumperLitsener, which is added to the whole frame
   public void moveBumperLeft()
   {
      bumper.setX(bumper.getX()-20);
      //System.out.println("moving bumper left");
   }

   public void moveBumperRight()
   {
      bumper.setX(bumper.getX()+20);
      //System.out.println("moving bumper right");
   }
   /*

   public class Key extends KeyAdapter
   {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {   
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            bumper.setX(bumper.getX()+10 );
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            bumper.setX(bumper.getX()-10 ); 
      }
   }
   */


   public void startGame()
   {
      isPlayingGame = true;
   }


   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      // draw myBuffer, then draw that onto g
         myBuffer.setColor(BACKGROUND);     
         myBuffer.fillRect(0,0,600,800); 
         setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 14));
         myBuffer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

         int b=1;
         int d=40;
         for(int r = 0; r < bary.length; r++)
         {  
            for(int c = 0; c < bary[0].length; c++)
            {

               bary[r][c] = new Brick(b, d,40,20, Color.BLUE);
               b=b+43;
               bary[r][c].draw(myBuffer);

            }
            d=d+23;
            b=1;
         }
         ball.draw(myBuffer);
         bumper.draw(myBuffer); 
         repaint();
         if(ball.getColor()==Color.BLACK)
         {
         myBuffer.setFont(new Font("MS Comic Sans", Font.ITALIC, 45));
         myBuffer.drawString("GAME OVER!", 168, 300);
         ball.move(0, 0, 0, 0);
         }
      g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
   }

   private class Listener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         GamePanel.this.getTopLevelAncestor().requestFocus();
         startGame(); // starts game when button is pressed
         System.out.println("Game is starting!");              
      }
   }  

   private void death(Ball ball)
   {
      double d = ball.getY() + ball.getRadius();

      if(d>800.0)
      {
         ball.setX(300);
         ball.setY(400);
         ball.setdx(ball.getdx()*-1);
         ball.setdy(ball.getdy()*-1);
         ball.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      }
   }

    /* private void collide(Ball ball, Bumper b)
   {
      double d = distance(ball.getX(), ball.getY(), b.getX(), b.getY());  
      if(d <= 37.5)
      {
        ball.move();
         hits++;
      }
   }*/
  // private double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
 //  {
   //   return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) +  Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2.0)));     // enter the calculation here.
   //}


}
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Swing is also double buffered by default, so you don't need to implement your own buffering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you have a single Listener class and two buttons that have registered against the listener (`sbutton` and `rbutton`). It'd be easier if you had different classes that implemented `ActionListener`, but let's move past that for now.

You need to make modifications to your `actionPerformed` method such that:

1. You can differentiate the source of the action - i.e. which button was pressed - Reset or the Start? Hint: use the getSource() method from ActionEvent
2. If the button pressed was the Reset button, you need to reset the GUI to its initial state

Comment: Sorry.. how do I do all of that? Our teacher didn't really teach us this. I'm just going off of what I found on the internet...